# Pip support with embeddable Python on wine in Docker

Tags: linux, python, docker, wine, pip

I am using an architecture which supports Windows system only. I have setup a Jenkins server for CI/CD. I am using Wine with Ubuntu:20.04 in Docker to build my source and package it on Jenkins.

I also wanted Python3.8 to make my builds work, so I am using embed python (Had faced issues while installing .msi python installer on Wine). Now, I require few packages that does not come with and has to be installed using PIP. Upon few searches I came to know that there is no official PIP support for embed python, but with few hacks, we can make it work. I tried the solutions, it worked, but I am unable to install few libraries like uuid.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install gnupg2 wget software-properties-common -y \
    && wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key \
    && apt-key add winehq.key \
    && apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main' \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends winehq-stable

RUN wine --version

RUN mkdir -p /wine/python

RUN cd /wine/python \
    && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.8/python-3.8.8-embed-amd64.zip \
    && unzip python-3.8.8-embed-amd64.zip \
    && rm -f python-3.8.8-embed-amd64.zip

ENV WINEPREFIX /wine

ENV WINEPATH Z:\\wine\\python\\Scripts;Z:\\wine\\python

# A hack to make pip work with embedded python.
ENV WINEARCH win64
ENV WINEDEBUG fixme-all

RUN wineboot --init

RUN cd /wine/python \
   && mv python38._pth python38._pth.backup \
   && wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

RUN wineboot --restart
# We need to provide random value to initialize Python during docker build
ENV PYTHONHASHSEED=4294967295
RUN cd /wine/python \
    && wine cmd /c python --version \
    && wine cmd /c python get-pip.py

RUN wine cmd /c python -m pip --help
RUN wine cmd /c pip3 install uuid


RUN ls /wine/python/Scripts
```

Installing uuid does not work:

```
Step 24/27 : RUN cd /scratch/wine/python     && wine cmd /c python --version     && wine cmd /c python get-pip.py
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c18f16be8ed0
Step 25/27 : RUN wine cmd /c python -m pip --help
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7599ef6a410d
Step 26/27 : RUN wine cmd /c pip3 install uuid
 ---> Running in 3df04cc0faa4
Collecting uuid
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError -2146893801] Windows Error 0x80090017
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: so are all these backflips you are doing just to avoid using Windows, but use windows-only python components? I usually think of python as being pretty cross-compatible, so its surprising to me that you cant just use a linux-native instance of python runtime.

Comment: Yes, that's true but funny at the same time, but for CI/CD, as we want to develop a smooth process. Due to few limitations, I am unable to use Windows docker image, and has to use Wine with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The issue boils down to a problem with `os.urandom()`. If you run `wine pip install -v uuid` in your container you will see the offending line: `File "uuid.py", line 782, in uuid4`. That line uses `os.urandom()`.

The issue can be reproduced with `wine python -c 'import os; os.urandom(1)'`

`os.urandom`s [documentation is mentioning a change of the underlying function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) from [`CryptGenRandom()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/56e8c87e84ede369b53e502f328876c1ad03fea6/Python/bootstrap_hash.c#L79) to [`BCryptGenRandom()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/441797d4ffb12acda257370b9e5e19ed8d6e8a71/Python/bootstrap_hash.c#L54) starting from Python 3.11. Changing your example to use Python 3.11 fixes the issue:

```
FROM debian:bookworm
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wine wine32:i386 \
    unzip wget ca-certificates

RUN mkdir -p /wine/python

RUN cd /wine/python \
    && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.4/python-3.11.4-embed-win32.zip \
    && unzip python-*.zip \
    && rm -f python-*.zip

ENV WINEPREFIX /wine
ENV WINEPATH Z:\\wine\\python\\Scripts;Z:\\wine\\python

RUN cd /wine/python \
  && rm python*._pth \
  && wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

RUN wineboot --init
RUN wineboot --restart
# We need to provide random value to initialize Python during docker build
ENV PYTHONHASHSEED=4294967295
RUN cd /wine/python \
    && wine python --version \
    && wine python get-pip.py

RUN wine python -m pip --help
RUN wine pip3 install uuid
RUN ls /wine/python/Scripts
```